# No python device connection in docker container

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, pyserial

I'm currently running a python script inside a docker container on an ubuntu machine. The script processes the input from a serial device with pyserial.
Everytime when I start the script I have no real connection to the device, it always throws this error:

```
serial.serialutil.SerialException: [Errno 16] could not open port /dev/ttyACM3: [Errno 16] Device or resource busy: '/dev/ttyACM3'
```

Note: The device isn't used in any other process, so there should be no reason to throw this error.

```
while True:
    try:
        self.serialSource = serial.Serial(self.inputDevice)
        self.serialSource.timeout = 0.5
        break
    except serial.serialutil.SerialException as e:
        print(str(e))
        time.sleep(1)
        continue
```

If I'm running the script directly on the host machine, then it seems to work as expected.
I think there might be a problem with the docker configuration.

I simply use docker-compose to attach the device to the container like this:

```
devices:
  - "/dev/ttyACM3:/dev/ttyACM3"
```

setup info:

- host os: ubuntu 18.04
- docker: 18.06.1-ce, build e68fc7a
- docker-compose: 1.22.0, build f46880fe
- docker image: "python:3.7.0"
- pyserial: 3.4

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with needing to share a port from your machine to the docker container? e.g. 
`ports:

      - 7051:7051`

Comment: It may need a [capability](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#runtime-privilege-and-linux-capabilities) that is dropped by docker. Try e.g. `--cap-add SYS_RAWIO` or `--cap-add SYS_TTY_CONFIG`. Try broad `--cap-add ALL`. Does it work with `--privileged`?

Comment: @mviereck Thanks a lot for your input with the capabilities. I could solve it by adding `--cap-add SYS_ADMIN`. It did not work with `--privileged`.

Comment: Good! Be aware that `SYS_ADMIN` for containers is a security risk, the container gains a lot of power. If you find a less permissive capability, it would be better. Try `--cap-add ALL --cap-drop SYS_ADMIN` to check whether another capability would work, too. You can also try `--security-opt seccomp=unconfined`.

Comment: @mviereck I already tested if other capabilities would work. Unfortunately only `SYS_ADMIN` seems to work for me, also `seccomp=unconfined` is not enough.
But I see why `SYS_ADMIN` isn't the best solution, is there a way to restrict `SYS_ADMIN` itself?

Comment: I am not sure why it needs `SYS_ADMIN` at all. Maybe if the device would be initialized on host and the container only sends and receives data, it would not need the capability. `SELinux` could be able to restrict `SYS_ADMIN` capabilities, but I am not experienced with it.